# WINAPI/Winapi C++, отрисовка Bitmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, bitmap, context

При отрисовке изображения Bitmap оно накладывается на само себя, а если выносить вне, то происходит мерцание изображения.

```
void DrawBitmap(HDC hDC, int x, int y, HBITMAP hBitmap)
{
    HBITMAP hbm, hOldbm;
    HDC hMemDC;
    BITMAP bm;

    // Создаем контекст памяти, совместимый
    // с контекстом отображения
    hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

    // Выбираем изображение bitmap в контекст памяти
    hOldbm = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

    // Если не было ошибок, продолжаем работу
    if (hOldbm)
    {

        // Определяем размеры изображения
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bm);


        // Рисуем изображение bitmap
        TransparentBlt(hDC, x, y, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight,
            hMemDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, RGB(0, 0, 0));

        // Восстанавливаем контекст памяти
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldbm);
    }

    // Удаляем контекст памяти
    DeleteDC(hMemDC);
}


void Draw(HDC* hdc)
{
    HDC hMem = CreateCompatibleDC(*hdc);
    SelectObject(hMem, BGround);
    AddPlanets(&hMem);
    BitBlt(*hdc, 0, 0, sizeX, sizeY, hMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteDC(hMem);
}

void AddPlanets(HDC * hdc)
{
    DrawBitmap(*hdc, MovementPlanet(150).first, MovementPlanet(150).second, Planets[0]);
}
```

Вызываю Draw в WM_PAINT + есть Timer, который вызывает InlidateRect
Как сделать, чтобы не накладывался?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Варианты 1. Рисовать в отдельный bitmap-буфер и потом копировать весь bitmap на экран. 2. Поискать и включить двойную буферизацию в Canvas DC-контексте устройства вывода.

Comment: Может быть вам стоит использовать DirectX или OpenGL. Вообще WinAPI плохо подходит для отрисовки динамической графики.

Comment: Покажите WndProc

Comment: case WM_TIMER:
  switch (wParam)
  {
  case 1:
   InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
  }
 case WM_COMMAND:
  if (wParam == 1)
   DestroyWindow(hwnd);
  break;
 case WM_ERASEBKGND:
  return FALSE;
 case WM_PAINT:
 {
  hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  Draw(&hdc);
  EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
 }
 break;

Comment: "case WM_ERASEBKGND: return FALSE" тут надо вернуть TRUE. TRUE означает, что система не будет стирать фон окна перед очередной его отрисовкой. Но, соответственно, Вы сами должны будете закрасить фон нужным цветом. Стирание фона и отрисовку лучше реализовать через двойной буфер. В таком случае, оконный HDC на каждую перерисовку обновится лишь один раз (а не 2, как минимум, при стандартной обработке WM_ERASEBKGND). Т.е. мерцания не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо просто использовать теневой буфер.

```
void Paint(PAINTSTRUCT &ps)
{
    HDC hMemDC, hTempDC;
    HGDIOBJ hMemBmp, hSysBmp;
    int cx, cy;

    // создаем теневой буфер
    cx = ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left;
    cy = ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top;
    hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);
    hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(ps.hdc, cx, cy);
    hSysBmp = SelectObject(hMemDC, hMemBmp);
    SetViewportOrgEx(hMemDC, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, nullptr);

    hTempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);

    // закрашиваем фон
    SelectObject(hTempDC, hBkBitmap);
    BitBlt(hMemDC, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, cx, cy, hTempDC, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, SRCCOPY);

    // накладываем прозрачный растр
    SelectObject(hTempDC, hTransparentBitmap);
    TransparentBlt(hMemDC, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, cx, cy, hTempDC, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, cx, cy, RGB(0, 0, 0));

    SelectObject(hTempDC, hSysBmp);
    DeleteDC(hTempDC);

    // выводим содержимое теневого буфера на экран
    BitBlt(ps.hdc, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, cx, cy, hMemDC, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hMemDC, hSysBmp);
    DeleteObject(hMemBmp);
    DeleteDC(hMemDC);
}
```

Для примера, я накидал похожий по функционалу проект
на основе стандартной болванки vs:

[Готовый exe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dngb2mnlq5zqe9/so-738711.exe?dl=0)
[Архив с проектом](https://www.dropbox.com/s/907hkw5wfwhj5z1/so-738711.zip?dl=0)